# UE5.3 New EnhancedInputAction confused with strange Behaviour of the triggered pin (FPS Game)

Tags: button, input, game-development, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am working on a FPS game in Unreal Engine 5.3 and have implemented basic weapon firing handeled by the server, following [This Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhrijWnJdyE). While Ive made a few changes these only affect the weapon logic, not that of the shooting itself.

[Weapon Input Blueprints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Cjr.png),

[Shoot Weapon On Server Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxSCT.png),

[Svr_ShootWeapon function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoj1W.png).

When using the old Unreal Engine input system as shown in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Cjr.png) everything works as expected. However using the new Unreal Engine EnhancedInputAction which we are using in our project I run into some problems. From research it seems that the corresponding pins to the previous "Pressed" and "Released" pins are now "Triggered" and "Completed".

[Weapon Input EnhancedInputAction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4w0V.png).

However, using this, most times the first shot fired will be fired twice, sometimes even three times, instead of once for a single input.

[2 Line Traces from Single input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsNBr.jpg).

This does not happen with the old input system but does with the new. Does anyone know why this might be the case? I have the idea that the "Triggered", which runs every frame manages to get multiple inputs through to the server before it sets the isFiring bool to true but thats only speculation as I would assume the setting of the boolean shouldnt take more than a single tick. And in this case why doesnt it happen with the old "Pressed" pin?

Edit:

[Input Action and Context Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEhvp.png)

Changing the input to be consumed also does not fix the issue.

Comment: Can you show screenshots of your `InputAction` and the `InputMappingContext` that you created for the new input system to work?

Comment: @Samaursa I added them in an edit.

Comment: sorry, took a while to reply here, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the `Started` execution pin which will only fire once assuming your `InputAction` Trigger (in your `InputMappingContext`) is `Down` and not `Pulse`

[image]

[image]

If you want Triggered to only fire once, you need to make sure that the Trigger in your Input Action is set to `Pressed`

[image]

Comment: Using started is what I ended up doing as well and I understand why it works. But what I dont understand is why it works the same way when using triggered with the only difference that it fires the first shot twice. This is especially confusing to me since it seems that the 'Triggered' pin is meant to replace the old 'Pressed' pin which when using that behaves completely normal.

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact setup that causes Triggered to only fire twice. However, I tested this with a vanilla UE5.3 project and `Triggered` will fire multiple times if the InputAction `Trigger` is set to `Down`. If you change the InputAction `Triggers` to `Pressed` then the `Triggered` execution pin in the event only fires once. I've updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, yea I think what confused me is that I expected the old pressed trigger in normal input actions to behave the same way as the new triggered pin but didnt realize that it was set to pulse instead of pressed. So essentially there is much more control now over how to interpret an input but the chance isnt that well documented so changing from the old to the new system leads to confusion.